# C мощью функции char *strrchar (const *src, char ch) находит последнее вхождение символа ch в строку src.Происходит ошибка компиляции

Tags: c, указатели

Мне нужно с помощью функции char *strrchar (const *src, char ch) найти последнее вхождение символа ch в строку src.Функция должна возвращать указатель на результат. Написал функцию,которая вроде должна работать, но при попытке запуска выдает ошибку:cast to pointer from integer of different size. Как можно исправить эту ошибку чтобы программа заработала?
вот мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *strrchar(const char *src, char ch){
int m=1,i, res = -1;
while(src[m-1] != 0){
    m++;
}
if(*src=='\0') return NULL;
else for(i=m;i>-1;i--){
    if(*(src+i)==ch) res=res+i+1;
    if(*(src+i)==ch) break;
}
if (res=='\0') return NULL;
else return (char*)res;//вот на этой строчке происходит ошибка
}
int main(void){
    const char *s="testtest";
    printf("%s",strrchar(s,'s'));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну так `res` — это просто число, вот компилятор и *предупреждает* — вы точно хотите его превратить в указатель на `char`? Что вы вообще хотите в этом коде сделать? Что вернуть?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы функция находила последнее вхождение символа в строку.Вернуть мне нужно указатель на результат

Comment: почему у вас res=res+i+1, а не выражение с src?

Answer (score 0):

Если в целочисленной переменной `res` вы пытаетесь запомнить *индекс* в массиве `src` по которому расположен искомый символ (в чём я не уверен до конца...), то возвращать нужно `src + res`.

Если указатель `src` имеет тип `const char*`, а возвращаемый функцией тип есть `char*`, то дополнительно потребуется снять константность: `(char*)(src + res)`.

Но в целом, вашу функцию я бы переписал так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

const char *strrchar(const char *src, char ch) {
    if (!src) return NULL;

    const char* res = NULL;
    for (;; ++src) {
        if (*src == ch)
            res = src;
        if (*src == '\0')
            break;
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void) {
    const char *s = "testtest";
    printf("%s\n", strrchar(s,'s'));
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Вывод](https://ideone.com/FQucDj):

```
st
```

P.S. Спецификатор преобразования `"%s"` требует, чтобы в функцию `printf` был передан ненулевой указатель, иначе поведение не определено. Т.к. функция `strrchar` может вернуть нулевой указатель, то нужно проявлять осторожность, передавая в `printf` непосредственный результат вызова `strrchar`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131716/discussion-on-answer-by-wololo-c---char-strrchar-const-src-char).